# Apply filtering on dataframe based on the input from other sheet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I am trying to filter main dataset(Pandas Dataframe) by applying filters (inputs from the another spreadsheet).

**Main data set:**

```
+---------+--------+-----+-----------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------------+----------+
| Cust Id | gender | Age | Indicator | X Indicator | State | foreign_ind | Eu Resident | address1 |
+---------+--------+-----+-----------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------------+----------+
|  987685 | M      |  65 | Y         | N           | TX    | N           | N           | XYZ,USA  |
|  987686 | F      |  54 | Y         | N           | NJ    | N           | N           | XYZ,USA  |
|  987687 | M      |  75 | Y         | Y           | NJ    | N           | N           | XYZ,USA  |
|  987688 | M      |  45 | N         | Y           | NY    | N           | N           | XYZ,USA  |
|  987689 | F      |  45 | Y         | Y           | NJ    | N           | N           | XYZ,USA  |
+---------+--------+-----+-----------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

Below is the config list which we are taking inputs from the end user in spreadsheet format and applying this conditions on top of the main dataset.

**Where condition inputs from another spreadsheet:**

```
+-------------+-----------+--------+------------------------------+---------+-----------+--------+
|   column1   | operator1 | value1 | Logical Condition(And or OR) | column2 | operator2 | value2 |
+-------------+-----------+--------+------------------------------+---------+-----------+--------+
| gender      | ==        | F      |                              |         |           |        |
| gender      | ==        | M      |                              |         |           |        |
| Age         | >=        | 75     | ||                           | Age     | >=        |     45 |
| Indicator   | ==        | Y      |                              |         |           |        |
| X Idnicator | ==        | Y      |                              |         |           |        |
| State       | ==        | NJ     |                              |         |           |        |
+-------------+-----------+--------+------------------------------+---------+-----------+--------+
```

**Expected output dataframe after applying filters.**

```
+---------+--------+-----+-----------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------------+----------+
| Cust Id | gender | Age | Indicator | X Indicator | State | foreign_ind | Eu Resident | address1 |
+---------+--------+-----+-----------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------------+----------+
|  987687 | M      |  75 | Y         | Y           | NJ    | N           | N           | XYZ,USA  |
|  987689 | F      |  45 | N         | Y           | DL    | N           | N           | XYZ,USA  |
+---------+--------+-----+-----------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: Is the input spreadsheet always the same?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution but you'll have to alter the input spreadsheet slightly. It should look like the table below:

```
         Label Operator Condition Value
0       gender                 ==     F
1       gender        |        ==     M
2          Age        &        >=    75
3          Age        &        >=    45
4    Indicator        &        ==     Y
5  X Indicator        &        ==     Y
6        State        &        ==    NJ
```

The table lists the filtering criteria. Conditions applied to the same criteria must be written in consecutive rows for the code to work. In your example, gender and age.

Your table:

```
        gender  Age Indicator X Indicator State foreign_ind Eu Resident address1
Cust Id
987685       M   65         Y           N    TX           N           N  XYZ,USA
987686       F   54         Y           N    NJ           N           N  XYZ,USA
987687       M   75         Y           Y    NJ           N           N  XYZ,USA
987688       M   45         N           Y    NY           N           N  XYS,USA
987689       F   45         Y           Y    NJ           N           N  XYS,USA
```

Output:

```
        gender  Age Indicator X Indicator State foreign_ind Eu Resident address1
Cust Id
987687       M   75         Y           Y    NJ           N           N  XYZ,USA
987689       F   45         Y           Y    NJ           N           N  XYS,USA
```

Code:

```
i = 0
filter_string = 'df'
while i < conditions.shape[0]:
    if i == conditions.shape[0] - 1:
        if conditions.iloc[i,0] == conditions.iloc[i-1,0]:
            label = conditions.iloc[i,0]
            operator = conditions.iloc[i,1]
            condition = conditions.iloc[i,2]
            value = conditions.iloc[i,3]
            if type(value) == 'int':
                string = str(operator + '(df[\'' + label + '\']' + condition + str(value) + '))]')
                filter_string += string
                i += 1
            else:
                string = str(operator + '(df[\'' + label + '\']' + condition + '\''+ str(value) + '\'))]')
                filter_string += string
                i += 1
        else:
            label = conditions.iloc[i,0]
            operator = conditions.iloc[i,1]
            condition = conditions.iloc[i,2]
            value = conditions.iloc[i,3]
            if type(value) == 'int':
                string = str(operator + '(df[\'' + label + '\']' + condition + str(value) + ')]')
                filter_string += string
                i += 1
            else:
                string = str(operator + '(df[\'' + label + '\']' + condition + '\''+ str(value) + '\')]')
                filter_string += string
                i += 1
    elif i == 0:
        if conditions.iloc[i,0] == conditions.iloc[i+1,0]:
            value = conditions.iloc[i,3]
            label = conditions.iloc[i,0]
            operator = conditions.iloc[i,1]
            condition = conditions.iloc[i,2]
            value = conditions.iloc[i,3]
            if type(value) == 'int':
                string = operator + '[((df[\'' + label + '\']' + condition + str(value) + ')'
                filter_string += string
                i += 1
            else:
                string = operator + '[((df[\'' + label + '\']' + condition + '\''+ str(value) + '\')'
                filter_string += string
                i += 1
        else:
            value = conditions.iloc[i,3]
            label = conditions.iloc[i,0]
            operator = conditions.iloc[i,1]
            condition = conditions.iloc[i,2]
            value = conditions.iloc[i,3]
            if type(value) == 'int':
                string = operator + '[(df[\'' + label + '\']' + condition + str(value) + ')'
                filter_string += string
                i += 1
            else:
                string = operator + '[(df[\'' + label + '\']' + condition + '\''+ str(value) + '\')'
                filter_string += string
                i += 1
    else:
        if conditions.iloc[i,0] == conditions.iloc[i+1,0]:
            value = conditions.iloc[i,3]
            label = conditions.iloc[i,0]
            operator = conditions.iloc[i,1]
            condition = conditions.iloc[i,2]
            value = conditions.iloc[i,3]
            if type(value) == 'int':
                string = operator + '((df[\'' + label + '\']' + condition + str(value) + ')'
                filter_string += string
                i += 1
            else:
                string = operator + '((df[\'' + label + '\']' + condition + '\''+ str(value) + '\')'
                filter_string += string
                i += 1
        elif conditions.iloc[i,0] == conditions.iloc[i-1,0]:
            value = conditions.iloc[i,3]
            label = conditions.iloc[i,0]
            operator = conditions.iloc[i,1]
            condition = conditions.iloc[i,2]
            value = conditions.iloc[i,3]
            if type(value) == 'int':
                string = operator + '(df[\'' + label + '\']' + condition + str(value) + '))'
                filter_string += string
                i += 1
            else:
                string = operator + '(df[\'' + label + '\']' + condition + '\''+ str(value) + '\'))'
                filter_string += string
                i += 1
        else:
            value = conditions.iloc[i,3]
            label = conditions.iloc[i,0]
            operator = conditions.iloc[i,1]
            condition = conditions.iloc[i,2]
            value = conditions.iloc[i,3]
            if type(value) == 'int':
                string = operator + '(df[\'' + label + '\']' + condition + str(value) + ')'
                filter_string += string
                i += 1
            else:
                string = operator + '(df[\'' + label + '\']' + condition + '\''+ str(value) + '\')'
                filter_string += string
                i += 1

print(eval(re.sub("'(\d+)'", r'\1', filter_string)))
```

**Edit:** Note: this will only work for queries where multiple criteria are applied to the same label as in your example. It won't work if you want to query males older than 45 and females older than 60, for example. If needed, it can easily be added by including some alterations.